# Why does Excel add leading apostrophes to some of my text cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, text-formatting, cells

I have a worksheet containing, among other things, a table object. All data in the worksheet was added by me manually, including the data and column headers in the table.

I just noticed that in 13 of the 16 table column headers, Excel has added a leading apostrophe to the header. In the other 3, the column header does not have the leading apostrophe. Investigating further, I found 5 more cells (outside the table) where Excel has added a leading apostrophe to the text content.

All other cells do not have the leading apostrophe. With the exception of the table totals row, all other cells either contain text or are empty.

When I try to remove the leading apostrophe from the cell contents, it's immediately re-added when I hit Enter. When I type new content for these cells, the apostrophe is added every time. When I enter numerical data (recognized and right-outlined), and then change the content to text again, the apostrophe re-appears.

In the otherwise identical cells that do not have an apostrophe, this behavior does not occur. Entering text results in text content without apostrophe.

All cells have General formatting.

What's causing this apostrophe to appear, and how do I get rid of it?

Edit: It's something in the cell formatting, because I can make the cell behave normally by erasing its formatting. But there is nothing set in the Cell Properties, and like I said, number formatting is set to General.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "why" is simple:  those apostrophes are present in EVERY cell containing or being treated as text. Excel does not normally display them, either in the formula editor or in the grid's display of the contents, but they exist.

The places they show are places that Excel has been coerced into displaying them. One way is the obvious, that of actually typing one before completing one's entry or edit. However, other mechanisms make them visible as well.

Corresponding characters exist for the other basic alignment formattings, "center" `(^)` and "right" `(")`. Again, not normally shown to us humans.

One way I know of to get one is to do the following:

1. Format a cell as TEXT.
2. Type `=746` in it. (Entering a number makes a difference.)
3. Edit the cell to include an apostrophe after the `=` before the `7`.
4. Press `Enter`.

The cell will display `=746` on the grid, but in the formula editor, you will see `'='746`. Note the new apostrophe before the `=`.

This is a situation in which the exact material being handled in the circumstances ends up with Excel showing the apostrophe. Edit the cell, removing the `'` AFTER the `=` and to replace `746` with `abc` (so placing clearly textual character in place of the numeric characters) and press `Enter`. Even though the cell is formatted as text and contains what is clearly text, Excel will still show the leading apostrophe. Once shown, it does not seem to stop displaying them.

Even copying text from elsewhere and pasting values does not. Once a cell has the displaying of the apostrophe turned on, it seems to stay on.

Importantly, it is simply displayed. It has no effect on calculations. For instance, `LEN()` will show 5 in the above example with 746, not 6.

You can often, though also often not, easily see the apostrophe being present during much data entry if you watch the entry closely. A leading apostrophe will often be visible during entry, though often it flickers. And then NOT present in the displayed cell contents, either on the grid or in the formula editor.

They are not harmful in any way, just disturbing. Probably why no one seems to have delved much into how to cause them, only to remove them. Or more properly, stop displaying them.

(Since you — pointedly — disdain the idea of anything about how to stop their display, I shall not mention one easy way. Perhaps it is one of the three ways `harrymc` links to.)

There isn't much lying about regarding why Excel comes to show some, though the little I've read suggests an action is taken that triggers Excel (what is called "coercion" when done on purpose to make Excel do things it does not normally do). Not necessarily a wrongful action at all, just an action. (The following does NOT happen. It is just a quick pretend example of a series of actions as I do not teach this subject and have a real such example in my pocket.) For instance, cells with a General format have entries, some numeric. One creates a Table using them as headers. Excel converts whatever is in them to text. Any purely numeric cell values start having their formatting characters shown (leading apostrophe in your case). (Again, just a pretend example that actually does not happen.)

To summarize, they are always present, just not shown.

(A little more for the "746" example above:  If you copy the formatting of the cell that shows the leading apostrophe to another cell (so formats are identical), then paste the value of the copied "746" cell (`'='746`) to it, the leading apostrophe is gone. Well, that happens, things like that anyway, with Excel. Then recalcing or editing the cell causes it to revert to how you expected it to be. But in this case it does not. So the exact FORM of things is not the issue, but rather the sequence of actions that led to that form, they typing steps and so on. Odd, no?)

Comment: Thanks, @jeorje, that's very interesting. Never to old to learn something new about Excel; I've never known that text content is always preceded by apostrophe.

Comment: And it's not so much that I disdain removal methods, rather that none of those three methods work (I did try), and I see no reason why they would.

Comment: Accepting this as answer, because the information that the apostrophes are always present in cells with text content, is the answer that explains it all. It implies that showing or hiding the apostrophe is formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Leading apostrophes force excel to treat the cell’s contents as a
text value.
Even if the cell contains a number or date, Excel will treat it as
text.
The apostrophe can only be seen in the Formula bar when selecting the
cell, and otherwise stays invisible.

This way, one may avoid entering a value like `Jan-01` and Excel
converting it to a date and formatting it according to the global date format.

You may remove these apostrophes, as explained for example in the article
[How to Remove Apostrophe in Excel (3 Easy Ways)](https://spreadsheetplanet.com/remove-apostrophe-in-excel/),
but better ensure in that case that Excel still treats these cells as text.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc. All of that is true, and none of it pertains to my question. I think it's best to read my questions carefully before responding.

Comment: Excel adds this for exactly the reason described in my answer. Why doesn't it apply to your question?

Comment: Like I said: read the question. I'm talking about cells with text content. I'm talking about a worksheet in which some cells with text content have spontaneously acquired the apostrophe, and others don't have it. The three methods in the article you refer to have no effect, and I don't see why they would have.

Comment: The methods in the link are for *removing* the apostrophes. Why Excel decides that some columns require them is unknown. One method that I tried was to select the cells or column, then do *Home > Editing group > Clear > Clear Formats*. This cleared this condition for me, but then numerical strings get interpreted as numbers.

Comment: Like I said: the methods in the link do not work. None of them remove the apostrophes (I tried), and I don't see any reason why they would.

Comment: And yes, removing formatting removes the apostrophes, which is what I already pointed out in my addition to my original question. There's no formatting though, at least nothing visible in the Cell Properties dialog. So it remains a mystery what exactly is removed.

Comment: Your answer did not pertain to my question, because your answer explains about the use of apostrophes to ensure that (potentially) numerical values are interpreted as text, and I'm clearly asking about cells with text content. Also, your answer describes the general purpose of the apostrophe, and I'm asking about a distinct difference betwen cells with similar content, half of which do and half don't display the apostrophe. Finally, your answer links to methods for removal that don't work. (Clearing formatting is the only thing that does.)

Comment: The answer @jeorje posted provided the essential information: apostrophe is present in all cells with text content (interesting, news to me) and becomes visible (in the formula bar) under some circumstances.

Comment: It would have been better if that user could provide a link to prove his claims.

Comment: It's easy to prove that all cells with text content contain an apostrophe: enter text in two cells, but precede only one of them with an apostrophe. That one will retain its apostrophe whatever you do. Copy its formatting to the apparently apostrophe-less cell, and the apostrophe appears. Since only formatting was copied, this proves that the apostrophe was already present. It also proves that showing the apostrophe is formatting, which is also evident from the fact that it can be hidden by removing formatting. Still odd that this particular formatting is not visible in Cell Properties...

Comment: There's no argument about these pesky apostrophes and their weird handling by Excel. I would have liked the given info to be supported by some documentation from Microsoft about the internal formatting of Excel cells. As it is, this claim cannot be substantiated. I've defined cells as text and there was no apostrophe, unless one adds it manually. This is no proof.

Comment: The proof lies in the fact that when you copy _formatting_ from a cell with apostrophe to a cell without that has text content, the apostrophe appears. Since the apostrophe can be selected and deleted in the cell, it's content, not formatting. Since it appears by copying only formatting, it follows that it was always there.  I don't need MS documentation for that.

Comment: I prefer documentation. Empirical results are only a part of the whole picture.

Comment: It would be great if MS has bothered to document this. I wouldn't bet on it. And in my experience, unlike empirical results, MS documentation is sometimes wrong, so when in doubt, I go with incontrovertible empirics.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot edit the existing answer, nor comment, so I'll add this in response to the second comment as it could help you, and others.

I looked at those methods in the other answer's link and they all revolve around the idea of doing an operation that forces ("coerces" to use the usual term) Excel to evaluate the contents for data type and realize it is displaying them wrongly, then fix that. It is a method that works about 95% of the time I've tried it in situations in which it appeared that should be applicable. The remaining times, well, they never were clear. And usually those situations address more of a "was formatted as text, changed the format, now need to coerce the display to suit me" kind of thing than what you describe.

But I tried two of them and they did not work on the created situation I mentioned in my answer (the "746" situation... which, by the way, I cannot create today, not the way it worked yesterday, though I CAN create it). And as you say, why would they anyway? The situation is materially different from simply displaying something wrongly on the grid.

However, what worked in THIS situation, and maybe yours, yesterday and today, was for me to:

1. Format some other cell for TEXT.
2. Copy the offending cell, then paste values into the newly formatted cell. (At this point the offending leading apostrophe is no longer showing, in the newly formatted cell.)
3. Copy the newly formatted and pasted into cell, then paste, NOT paste values, back into the original cell.

All text, the whole way, not numbers that were formatted as text, then reformatted but still displayed as text (aligning to the left edge and so on).

However, after those steps, my leading apostrophe no longer showed in the formula editor when examining the original cell.

Perhaps such a method would work on your material, text to begin with, text to end with. For row material, even in a very used place, one could insert a row, do it, then delete the row, though a tighter idea would be to just insert a blank sheet to do the middle step into and out of, deleting the sheet after doing it.

Maybe someone who can edit will transfer this into my answer or write it up as a comment. Experience says someone will just delete it, but maybe humanity has turned a corner and they'll be helpful first.

Comment: There seems to be some unpredictability involved here. Your method does not work for me when I try it. Oh well, removing formatting and/or copying formatting from a cell without visible apostrophes does work, so I'll stick to that and accept your other answer (because that contains the essential information).

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have anything to add just sharing similar experience
I usually paste similar &&& formula from my Excel to notepad without the quote appearing. Today I paste it and quotes appear in some line,but not the other. I searched internet first and find this thread, I check back to my formula and find out I accidentally paste the line break while adjusting my formula

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/why-is-excel-adding-quotes-when-i-copy-a-cell/9633ca38-81b3-4c0f-981a-05e33c4ba419

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1155274)